# Insert element at Index as Array Lengthens

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Lets say I have an array of objects `var schedule`

Which I am looping through `forEach` to check whether there is a gap in this schedule for a given day by comparing the current element's end time with the next element's start time. If they are not the same then there is clearly a gap in the schedule.

This all works so far. The issue is in splicing "STUFF" at the correct index. Currently what happens is...for each iteration where I am splicing, the list length is growing by one, and so the [[magical index]] is not currently splicing at the correct index. (Not so magical yet).

```js
var schedule = [{s: "9:00 AM", e: "10:00 AM"}, {s: "11:00 AM", e: "12:00 PM"}, {s: "12:00 PM", e: "2:00 PM"}, {s: "5:00 PM", e: "7:00 PM"}]

schedule.forEach((element, index) => { 
         if(index+1 <= schedule.length -1){
              var nextElement= schedule[index+1]; 
              if( !element.e.isSame(nextElement.s)){
                    //PSEDUO CODE
                    schedule.splice([[magical index]], 0, "STUFF");
              };
         };  
    }
```

The desired output/result would look like this...with "STUFF"s inserted in the original schedule array
`var schedule = [{s: "9:00 AM", e: "10:00 AM"}, "STUFF", {s: "11:00 AM", e: "12:00 PM"}, {s: "12:00 PM", e: "2:00 PM"}, "STUFF", {s: "5:00 PM", e: "7:00 PM"}]`

Comment: where do you want the item to be in relation to the rest of the list elements?

Comment: I just edited my response to include my expected output, but basically right after the current element that is being looped through, since that would end up being between the elements being compared. between current element and next element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple and understandable solution. Hope it helps.

```js
var schedule = [{s: "9:00 AM", e: "10:00 AM"}, {s: "11:00 AM", e: "12:00 PM"}, {s: "12:00 PM", e: "2:00 PM"}, {s: "5:00 PM", e: "7:00 PM"}]
var newSchedule =[]; //new array that will contains the result 
const leng = schedule.length ;

schedule.forEach((element, index) => { 
  newSchedule.push(schedule[index]); //always add the schedule elements
  if(index+1 <= leng-1 ){
      var nextElement= schedule[index +1]; 
      if( element.e !== nextElement.s){
            newSchedule.push("STUFF"); //push the string "STUFF" if there is difference.
      };
      
  };  
});

console.log(newSchedule);
```

Comment: i did not think to just have a separate array, very simple way of doing it thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Without going too deep into your implementation, I can tell you what has always worked for me with "inserting-while-looping" problems:

## loop from end-to-start

When you alter the current index data, you don't need to care about the array's length or successors, which are affected by insert into the current index.

Unfortunately the `forEach` method does not provide it.

Fortunately it is not hard to write an own one, based on the original:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach2 = function(fun /*, thisp*/) {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun != "function") {
        throw new TypeError();
    }

    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     fun.call(thisp, this[i], i, this);
    }
};
var schedule = [
 {s: "9:00 AM", e: "10:00 AM"}, 
  {s: "11:00 AM", e: "12:00 PM"}, 
  {s: "12:00 PM", e: "2:00 PM"}, 
  {s: "5:00 PM", e: "7:00 PM"}
];

schedule.forEach2(function(element, index) { 
    var nextElement= schedule[index-1]; 
  if( nextElement && element.s !== nextElement.e){
        schedule.splice(index, 0, "STUFF");
    };
});
    
console.log(schedule);
```

Edit: note, that you need to inverse the logic inside the function too, otherwise it will not run correctly. However, with this solution you do not introduce a second array variable, which makes it interesting to work with larger sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You might do it within a simple for loop:

```js
var schedule = [{s: "9:00 AM", e: "10:00 AM"}, {s: "11:00 AM", e: "12:00 PM"}, {s: "12:00 PM", e: "2:00 PM"}, {s: "5:00 PM", e: "7:00 PM"}];

for (let i = 0; i < schedule.length; i++)
  if (schedule[i+1] && schedule[i].e !== schedule[i+1].s)
    schedule.splice(++i, 0, "STUFF");

console.log(schedule);
```

Comment: Great approach with skipping by using pre increment. I will remember that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach:

```js
var schedule = [{s: "9:00 AM", e: "10:00 AM"}, {s: "11:00 AM", e: "12:00 PM"},
                {s: "12:00 PM", e: "2:00 PM"}, {s: "5:00 PM", e: "7:00 PM"}]

const insertStuff = sched => sched.reduce((all, curr, idx) => 
  ((idx > 0 && curr.s !== sched[idx - 1].e) ? all.concat('STUFF') : all).concat(curr)
, [])

console.log(insertStuff(schedule))
```

This one uses much the same technique as Firas Omrane's answer.  But it turns it into a reusable function, and uses `reduce` rather than explicit loops.

I don't know your data, but I can imagine the need for a slight extension, if times can overlap, but you still want to report gaps.  This version uses a pretty inelegant `timeCompare`, but works much like the above:

```js
const timeCompare = (t1, t2) => {
  const [time1, meridian1] = t1.split(/\s/g);
  const [h1, m1] = time1.split(':').map(Number)
  const [time2, meridian2] = t2.split(/\s/g);
  const [h2, m2] = time2.split(':').map(Number)
  return (meridian1 === meridian2) 
     ? (h1 === h2) 
       ? (m1 === m2) ? 0 : (m1 < m2) ? -1 : 1 
       : (h1 < h2) ? -1 : 1 
     : (meridian1 === "AM") ? -1 : 1
}

const overlapped = [{s: "9:00 AM", e: "11:30 AM"}, {s: "11:00 AM", e: "12:00 PM"}, 
                    {s: "1:30 PM", e: "2:00 PM"}, {s: "5:00 PM", e: "7:00 PM"}]

const insertGap = sched => sched.reduce((all, curr, idx) => 
  (idx > 0 && timeCompare(curr.s,  sched[idx - 1].e) > 0) ? all.concat('GAP').concat(curr) : all.concat(curr)
, [])

console.log(insertGap(overlapped))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do this without mutating the array. Splice is one of the worst functions in javascript and is more headache than it's worth. I use this function all the time in production:

```
function addToArray(arr, item, i) {
  i === 0 ? i = 0 : i = i || arr.length;
  const arr1 = arr.slice(0, i);
  const arr2 = arr.slice(i);
  return arr1.concat([item].concat(arr2));
}
```

`i` is an optional argument. If omitted it puts the item on the end, otherwise it puts it in the specified index by slicing up to that index and from that index, and then concatting the arrays together with the desired insert in the middle of the two.

So in your loop, once your condition evals to true you could call the above function with the current index + 1 as your `i`. If your list was

```
[{s: "9:00 AM",  e: "10:00 AM"}, 
 {s: "11:00 AM", e: "12:00 PM"}, 
 {s: "12:00 PM", e: "2:00 PM"},
 {s: "5:00 PM",  e: "7:00 PM"}]
```

and you wanted to add an item after the second item you could just:

```
schedule = addToArray(schedule, "GAP", index + 1)
//where index is 1
```

resulting in

```
[{s: "9:00 AM",  e: "10:00 AM"}, 
 {s: "11:00 AM", e: "12:00 PM"}, 
 "GAP",
 {s: "12:00 PM", e: "2:00 PM"},
 {s: "5:00 PM",  e: "7:00 PM"}]
```

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: you should get two `GAP`s

Comment: i appreciate your response Robbie! would this method also insert a "GAP" between 2PM and 5PM?

Comment: yes but to make it clean you should mutate i, so after the first gap is put in `i++` so that your indices match up